# How to parse a remote XML file with PHP?

Tags: php, xml

I want to parse the following [XML file](http://smarkets.s3.amazonaws.com/oddsfeed.xml).

What I have so far is:

```
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement('http://smarkets.s3.amazonaws.com/oddsfeed.xml', LIBXML_NOCDATA, true);

foreach ($xml->odds->event as $item) {
    echo (string)$item->market;
}
```

But this does not work. Can you help me?

Comment: could you more accurately describe the issue; does it throw an exception, is xml null, is it an empty object etc

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have no idea which information you want to extract so here is an example how to get the attributes 'id' and 'slug' from all market nodes.

Just add `compress.zlib://` to your url to get the xml, for PHP 4.3.0 and up

```
<?php
$xml = simplexml_load_file('compress.zlib://http://smarkets.s3.amazonaws.com/oddsfeed.xml') or die("Error: Cannot create object");

foreach ($xml->event as $item) {
    echo $item->market['id'] . "<br>" . $item->market['slug'] . "<br><br>";
}
?>
```

Answer (score 6):

You can try with php [CURL](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php):

```
$ch = curl_init();
$url = 'http://smarkets.s3.amazonaws.com/oddsfeed.xml';

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING, 'UTF-8');

$data = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

$xml = simplexml_load_string($data);

print_r($xml);
```